# Show that the MLE for $p_{i\cdot}, p_{\cdot j}$ $\hat{p}_{i\cdot}=\frac{x_{i\cdot}}{n}$, $ \hat{p}_{\cdot j}=\frac{x_{\cdot j}}{n}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Show that the MLE for $p_{i\cdot}, p_{\cdot j}$ are $\displaystyle \hat{p}_{i\cdot}=\frac{x_{i\cdot}}{n}, \: \hat{p}_{\cdot j}=\frac{x_{\cdot j}}{n}$ where $p_{ij}=p_{i\cdot}p_{\cdot j}$

**attempt**

$$L(p\mid x)=\binom{n}{x}\prod_{i,j}p_{ij}^{X_{i,j}}$$

$\displaystyle \implies \log L = \log\binom{n}{x} + \sum_{i,j}x_{ij}\log p_{ij} \implies \frac{d\log L}{dp_{ij}} =  \frac{x_{ij}}{p_{ij}}$???

Essentially what I am stuck with is page 4 of https://slate.stat.ubc.ca/slate/SlateFile/2015-2016/Winter_Term2/STAT461561/Text/Assignment7.pdf;jsessionid=B79C018480DB35F4CA1C252A7022D422.tom

Why does $\displaystyle \frac{d\log L}{dp_{ij}}=\frac{x_{ij}}{p_{ij}}-n$ and not $\displaystyle \frac{x_{ij}}{p_{ij}}$?

Comment: Look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1731225/ There is linear constraint $\sum_{i,j}p_{ij}=1$ so every $p_{ij}$ appears twice in $L$.

Answer (score 1):

As @NCh noted, for the method of Lagrange multipliers we must add a term $\lambda(1-\sum_{ij}p_{ij})$ to our choice of Lagrangian, which would otherwise be the log-likelihood. So the quantities we want to be $0$ aren't $\frac{x_{ij}}{p_{ij}}$, but $\frac{x_{ij}}{p_{ij}}-\lambda$. Requiring these to all be $0$ implies $x_{ij}=np_{ij}$, so $\lambda=n$.